# Difference between boost::any and boost::variant when we use cout<<

Tags: c++

I have run the following piece of code successfully using `boost::variant<string, float>`. However, when I tried to use `boost::any` instead, I face mismatch operand error at `cout<<` instruction, the piece of code is :

```
for( vector<vector<vector<boost::any>>>::const_iterator i = masterList.begin(); i != masterList.end(); ++i)
{
    for( vector<vector<boost::any>>::const_iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
    {
        for( vector<boost::any>::const_iterator k = j->begin(); k != j->end(); ++k)
        { 
            cout<<*k<<' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any) offers full type erasure, all characteristics (such as streaming to a `std::ostream`) of the underlying type are erased. The only way to get back the type is by using the `any_cast` functions.

If you want partial type erasure, look at the [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_erasure) library of Steven Watanabe. Note that TypeErasure is an official Boost library since Boost 1.54.

Comment: [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) has been added to the latest beta release, and should be an official part of Boost within less than a month (assuming no major issues are brought up).

Comment: @Mankarse: Updated links as Boost 1.54 has now been released with the TypeErasure library.